# How can I add another database in my laravel project in heroku

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql, heroku

I have my laravel project deployed in heroku, but I only migrated the database that I have created eg: users, news. But I have another database that is not migrated from my laravel project. Meaning, it is a existing database and I'm only connecting it on my project. In my development stage, I can connect the second database using my codes below. But now, I will deploy my project in heroku and I dont know how can I connect the second database because in heroku's postgresSQL you can only create and migrate the database based on the migration folder in laravel. I dont know how to upload an sql file in heroku's postgresSql and in that way I can connect the second database using the codes below. Is this possible in heroku? Because the second database is important in my landing page. It includes some few `select` query.

Here are some of my codes including the connection of the second database.

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HoQcNyCc5KEGw4yjqpBIdKzTC+yeDoOJcerVMEVx+fs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=adminpanel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=ricjac8_orocoin
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=
```

database.php

```
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD','forge'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

GraphController.php - The one that has select query from my other database

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use View;
use App\News;
use Charts;
use App\Graph;
use App\Roadmap;
class GraphController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $allroad = Roadmap::all();
        $news = News::all();

        //the second database query
        $graphdetails = Graph::select()->where('id', 1)->get();
        return view('coin.news',compact('news','graphdetails','allroad'));
    }

}
```

graph.blade.php - the result of the select query being rendered in a chart

```
//other blade codes i didint include here.


@foreach ($graphdetails as $item)
@endforeach


 chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    chart.data = [{
      "tokens": "Sold Tokens",
      "values": {{$item->total_tokens}} - {{$item->sales_token}}
    },{
      "tokens": "Unsold Tokens",
      "values": {{$item->sales_token}}
    }];
  });
```

Graph.php model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Charts;
class Graph extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'ico_stages';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'total_tokens', 'base_price', 'min_purchase', 'max_purchase', 'soft_cap', 'hard_cap',
        'display_mode','private','user_panel_display','sales_token','sales_amount','status',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, and this config looks fine. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Thats my code in development stage sir. And it works. Now that im done, I want to connect the second database in my heroku app. And I dont know how because the tutorials I watched is adding a database that you created manually eg: creating migrations. My second database is an existing database that I didint migrate using laravel and I only do select queries only in that database.

Comment: can someone help me ? please

Comment: *I only do select queries only in that database* - how are you doing that? Show your code, please. Are you using Eloquent?

Comment: Okay sir i will edit my codes @Tarasovych

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another free shared hosting that uses MySQL. PostreSQL is a little bit different than MySQL.

Comment: Yes sir. I already solved it by choosing a different hosting site.

Comment: which one did you use, because i want have two or more database connected to my Laravel Application